# Wire components to the custom view inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Came up this question and did some quick experiments without no luck.

Basically, I made a simple single view project where the top view controller is a `UITableViewController`. For simplicity, I set the table view content to be "Static Cells". The table cell was a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, like this

```
@interface TopTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TableCellBottomView *bottomView;

@end
```

Both the properties were wired through control dragging. The `TableCellBottomView` is just a custom subclass of UIView like this

```
@interface TableCellBottomView : UIView

@end
```

Now I add a label inside this `TableCellBottomView` like the following picture showing

[image]

Can I wire this `bottom label` inside to my `TableCellBottomView`? Control dragging did not work for me here. I certainly could have added it programmatically inside `TableCellBottomView.m`. But if i could wire it here, it would be quite convenient, since I could also add a lot of other components and arrange them visually. Thanks!

Comment: make iboutlet always weak not strong.

Comment: Found this article http://mrmaksimize.com/ios/Custom-UITableViewCell-With-NIB/ and it looks what i need, but then i have to create a separate xib file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Xcode won't allow you to drag from your label to the bottom view .h file, but you can do it another way. Add the IBOutlet property to the .h file, then drag from the littler open circle to the left of the @property to your label in the storyboard, and that should work.

Comment: This sounds weird, but it did work for me. Reverse-dragging from the code to storyboard...

Answer (score 1):

You may set a tag for the label in Xcode and fetch the UILabel based on the tag wherever you need it:

[image: Set tag value]

If you use dynamic cells, you can do this in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Alternatively wire the cell to a property and then use that property to fetch it:

```
((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1]).text = @"Some text";
```

Comment: No, I am trying to move all the inner components into a separate view class. So the table cell itself looks cleaner

Comment: @marsant Ah, ok. Just saw rdelmar's solution and it is indeed a very nice one :-)